# SpeechRecognizer won't work on Android 11 if android:sharedUserId is set

Tags: android, permissions, speech-recognition

If android:sharedUserId is set in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.speechrecognizerapp"
    android:sharedUserId="com.example.speechrecognizerapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
```

SpeechRecognizer does not work on Android 11 (API level 30) as RecognitionListener.onError callback will return 5 (SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT).

If you check the logcat, it shows we are not allowed to perform RECORD_AUDIO:

```
12-22 10:49:49.503  1278  2519 E AppOps  : noteOperation
12-22 10:49:49.503  1278  2519 E AppOps  : java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package com.example.speechrecognizerapp:10451 under uid 10451 but it is really -1
...

12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       : Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox from uid 10243 or calling package com.example.speechrecognizerapp:10451 from uid 10451 not allowed to perform RECORD_AUDIO
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at android.app.AppOpsManager.noteProxyOp(AppOpsManager.java:7599)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at android.app.AppOpsManager.noteProxyOp(AppOpsManager.java:7626)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.android.apps.search.transcription.f.at.p(SourceFile:12)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.android.apps.search.transcription.f.at.j(SourceFile:2)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.android.apps.search.transcription.f.bl.fI(Unknown Source:2)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ct.fI(SourceFile:2)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.common.x.a.f.f(Unknown Source:2)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  at com.google.common.x.a.h.run(SourceFile:9)
12-22 10:49:49.506  5495  5868 W A       :  ... 5 more
...
12-22 10:49:49.509 15452 15452 E SpeechRecognizerApp: onError: 5
```

But SpeechRecognizer did work after removing sharedUserId and reinstalling the app. As you know, you cannot upgrade an App with sharedUserId to a newer version without sharedUserId from App market, so I don't know how to properly solve this problem. Please help me out.

The source code for test:
https://github.com/youjhihchao/SpeechRecognizerApp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the relevant issue I post to Google:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176129030